# jQuery controll dynamic element creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I'm facing the problem with, when I attach a file, remove button create dynamically for all input filed. I need which input field is attached, create a remove button for only that field. How do I control it for individual input field?

```js
$(document).on('change', ".wpcf7-file", function() {
    $('span:not(:has(button))').append('<button class="removeButton" type="button">remove</button>');
});

$(document).on('click', ".removeButton", function() {
    var file = this.previousSibling.value = '';
    $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap file-226"><input type="file" name="file-226" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" id="file1" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" aria-invalid="false"></span>
<br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap file-227"><input type="file" name="file-227" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" id="file1" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" aria-invalid="false"></span>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the currently clicked element is the input element, you have to target only the [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) *SPAN* element.

Try the following selector:

```
$(this).closest('span:not(:has(button))')
```

```js
$(document).on('change', ".wpcf7-file", function() {
  if(this.value.length) { // check if length not falsy
    $(this).closest('span:not(:has(button))').append('<button class="removeButton" type="button">remove</button>');
  }
  else
    $(this).next('.removeButton').remove(); // remove the button when cancel button is clicked
});
$(document).on('click', ".removeButton", function() {
  var file = this.previousSibling.value = '';
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap file-226"><input type="file" name="file-226" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" id="file1" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" aria-invalid="false"></span>
<br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap file-227"><input type="file" name="file-227" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" id="file1" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" aria-invalid="false"></span>
<br>
```

Comment: Thank You @mamun. Here I'm facing another problem. After a file attached a remove button created automatically that's fine. But without removing that file, if you again going to choose a file and press the cancel button. At that time remove button existed without the file attachment. Screenshot https://imgur.com/a/ormjDTf
How do here check the condition of, If file found remove button will create and if file not found or click the remove button, remove button HTML element will be removed.

Comment: @RashedulAlam, you can check the length to check if *cance*l button is clicked or not, if yes the remove the button using `.next('.removeButton').remove()`

Answer (score 0):

do a litle change in your below code please check:

```
$(document).on('change', ".wpcf7-file", function() {
$('span:not(:has(button))').append('<button class="removeButton" type="button">remove</button>');

});
```

Change it to

```
$(document).on('change', ".wpcf7-file", function() {
$(this).parents('span').append('<button class="removeButton" type="button">remove</button>');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `this` into a jQuery object first, then you can call `.siblings()` onto it, get the first sibling and set its `.val()` to ""

```js
$(document).on('change', ".wpcf7-file", function() {
    $('span:not(:has(button))').append('<button class="removeButton" type="button">remove</button>');

});


$(document).on('click', ".removeButton", function() {
    var file = $(this).siblings().first().val('');
    $(this).remove();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap file-226"><input type="file" name="file-226" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" id="file1" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" aria-invalid="false"></span>
<br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap file-227">
<input type="file" name="file-227" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" id="file1" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" aria-invalid="false"></span>
<br>
```